# Python program does not recieve response when connecting and sending data to SSL socket

Tags: python-3.x, ssl

I am trying to connect to an SSL socket hosted on an external server, send data and the service should respond which is what I am attempting to capture.  However the program will wait for a response and then timeout.

At a basic level I am trying to replicate the below openssl connection.  I am able to send a `ping` and the server responds `pong` so that I know everything is working.

`openssl s_client -quiet -connect server.server:443`

```
import socket
import ssl

hostname = "server.server"
context = ssl.create_default_context()

with socket.create_connection((hostname, 4433)) as sock:
    sock.settimeout(5)
    with context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=hostname) as ssock:
        print(ssock.version())
        ssock.send(b'ping')
        response = ssock.recv(1024)
        print(response)
    sock.close()
    print("SSL Socket Closed")
```

Comment: `1024` might be too high depending on what messages are exchanged and your client may be sitting idle waiting for more data. Either change the protocol to prefix messages by their length, or read thing in smaller amount and have a way to define "end of message".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing known about the server program. But my guess is that the server will read a line and only respond after the line was read. When trying with `openssl s_client` you enter `ping` followed by the `<Enter>` key - which will send `ping` followed by a newline character ('\n') to the server. With `ssock.send(b'ping')` in your code you will instead only send `ping` to the server and the newline character which is likely expected by the server. Because of this the server will hang while still trying to read a full line (which should end with `\n`). Thus, try to send `b'ping\n'` instead of only `b'ping'`.

Comment: That worked, now I just need to parse the returned `b'pong\r\n'`.